# Dynamically Linking a dll using reflection and passing delegates

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to dynamically load a dll and construct a `MyDllClass` object. My code is roughly as follows(unrelevant parts stripped):

**MyDllClass.cs**

```
namespace MyDllNameSpace
{
    public class MyDllClass
    {

        private EventCallBack m_DelegateCallBack = null;

        public MyDllClass(EventCallBack eventCallBack)
        {
            m_DelegateCallBack = eventCallBack;
        }

        public MyDllClass()
        {
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**MyDllCallBackNameSpace.cs**

```
namespace MyDllCallBackNameSpace
{
    public delegate void EventCallBack(string message);
}
```

I managed to construct the object using the empty constructor but I couldn't get other constructor working. I get `ArgumentException`

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke()  
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke()  
at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke() at MyProgram.InitMyObject()  
at ...
```

Here is my code:

**MyProgram.cs**

```
public void InitMyObject(EventCallBack callBack)
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(DLL_PATH);
    Type type = assembly.GetType(CLASS_NAME);
    ConstructorInfo[] constructors = type.GetConstructors();
    if (type != null)
    {
        // empty constructor, works!!!
        //return constructors[1].Invoke(new object[0]); 
        // This one gives InvalidArgument exception
        return constructors[0].Invoke(new object[] {callBack});
    }
    return null;
}
```

`MyDllCallBackNameSpace.cs` file has been added to both projects(the .dll & the .exe project) and references the same physical file on my drive. But I suspect that it is still treated as different. Any ideas why it is not working, or any workarounds?

Comment: Ask for the *specific* constructor you need.  Right now, using constructors[0] is a roll of the dice.  Use Type.GetConstructor() instead and pass `new Type[] { typeof(EventCallback) }`  If you get null back from GetConstructor then you've got a problem with EventCallback appearing in more than one assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this buy moving `MyDllCallBackNameSpace.cs` into another dll. Then I referenced that dll from both projects.

Answer (score 0):

ArgumentException for the [ConstructorInfo.Invoke Method (Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx) says, "The parameters array does not contain values that match the types accepted by this constructor." Are you sure that you're getting the constructor you expect when you do `constructors[0]`? Try `ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(EventCallback) });` instead of GetConstructors.

Comment: `GetConstructor` returns null in that case. Although I'm passing the same type of `EventCallback` argument. I guess I also need to create the arguments dynamically at run time.

Comment: What do you get if you do `Type callbackType = assembly.GetType("EventCallBack"); ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { callbackType });`?

Comment: `assembly.GetType("EventCallBack");` returns null

Comment: Try it with the full namespace.